# Не работает Update в хранимой процедуре MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, update

Прошу помощи с MSSQL.

Есть хранимая процедура:

```
USE [fbyc]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BK]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT * FROM [fbyc].[dbo].[BKNames]

UPDATE [fbyc].[dbo].[BKNames]
SET 
[Test4] = '4444444'
WHERE [Test3] = 'ttt'

SELECT * FROM [fbyc].[dbo].[BKNames]
```

Если вызываю ее из SSMS, то процедура выполняется нормально, значение в таблице BKNames меняется.

Если подключаюсь из python, то значение в таблице не меняется. причем выборка Select после Update показывает изменения, но в таблице они не сохраняются.

Comment: А у вас python приложение commit выполняет?

Comment: @SwaD, Спасибо, commit помог!